# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './slash_commands'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm really stuck on this, I have V13 code already and I wanna add slash commands which I have but for some reason I cant get past this and I cant find anything that explains what to do.

if anyone can please help me solve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
code: const { readdirSync } = require("fs"),
ascii = require("ascii-table");

let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading("Slash Commands", "Load status");

module.exports = (client) => {
        readdirSync("./slash_commands").forEach(dir => {
            const commands = readdirSync(`./slash_commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
    
            for (let file of commands) {
                let pull = require(`../slash_commands/${dir}/${file}`);

                client.slash_commands.set(pull.data.name, pull);
                table.addRow(file, '✅');
            
                if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name));
            }
        });
        // Log the table
        console.log(table.toString());
}
```

output:

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './slash_commands'
    at readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\codiene wrld\Desktop\dream\handlers\slash_command.js:8:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\codiene wrld\Desktop\dream\index.js:11:99)
```

Comment: post your code and the output from the console please

Comment: ok hopefully i did it right but i edited it

Comment: please add your file structure, thanks.

Comment: Is the path correct? Is the folder named exactly like in your code?

Comment: Try removing the `./`. I had the same issue today and although this was the correct path, It said _no such file ..._. So I removed the `./` and it worked again

Comment: I guess you dont have to specify the exact path but only the name of the target directory